# How to perform EJB DB RBAC with WildFly?

Tags: ejb-3.1, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I'm trying to create a rich client that performs EJB RMI to interact with a server/DB. Previously, I had communications working with the remoting system to authenticate a user. Then I tacked on HTTPS communications using a keystore and clustering to the environment. Everything worked at that point.

The file-based authentication was an interim step in moving towards database authentication & authorization. I may still have configurations from that lingering and effecting this new step, I'm not certain.

Below is the failure message when trying to authenticate via the client:

```
Jan 19, 2017 12:51:52 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient <clinit>
INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 2.1.4.Final
Jan 19, 2017 12:51:52 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
Jan 19, 2017 12:51:52 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
Jan 19, 2017 12:51:52 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
Jan 19, 2017 12:51:53 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector setupEJBReceivers
WARN: Could not register a EJB receiver for connection to 10.0.0.1:8443
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Failed to read server challenge [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/appsrv/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/domain/tmp/auth/local4807198060994958453.challenge (No such file or directory)]
   DIGEST-MD5: Server rejected authentication
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener.allMechanismsFailed(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:114)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:389)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:241)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:198)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:112)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$DelegatingChannelListener.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:1092)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit.run(JsseStreamConduit.java:446)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit.readReady(JsseStreamConduit.java:547)
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseStreamConduit$2.readReady(JsseStreamConduit.java:319)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:567)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:430)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.EndpointPool$PooledEndpoint.connect(EndpointPool.java:192)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NetworkUtil.connect(NetworkUtil.java:153)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.NetworkUtil.connect(NetworkUtil.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:78)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:161)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:118)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:47)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.getCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:281)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireCurrent(EJBClientContext.java:291)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getVer(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.clientapp.TestClient.authenticate(TestClient.java:208)
    at com.test.clientapp.BackgroundServiceEngine.run(BackgroundServiceEngine.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In my WildFly domain configuration, I added the following authentication module to the "ha" profile (the one assigned to my host controllers) in -> Security -> MySecurityDomain via the GUI:

```
name: testds01
code: Database
flag: required
module options: 
  dsJndiName = java:/TestDS01
  principalsQuery = SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?
  password-stacking = useFirstPass
  hashAlgorithm = MD5
  hashEncoding = BASE64
  hashCharset = utf-8
```

I also added the following authorization module to the same area:

```
name: testds01
code: Delegating
flag: required
module options:
  dsJndiName = java:/TestDS01
  rolesQuery = SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM roles INNER JOIN users ON users.role_id = roles.role_id WHERE users.username =?
```

Honestly, I don't know what the flag "required" means. Nor the code "Delegating". I just found these in a book I read.

My WildFly setup includes: 1x Domain Controller, 2x Host Controllers w/1 server each, 2x SQL databases. All 5 of these are separate VMs. So, In addition to the testds01 modules added above, I have testds02 modules added pointing to "java:/TestDS02".

Let me know if additional information is needed. I'm not sure I covered everything.

Update: It's probably useful to have the client properties I'm using to setup & perform RMI:

```
// Set TLS Properties
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "test.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "test.truststore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "testpass1");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "testpass2");

// Set Application Server Properties
properties = new Properties();
properties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "true");
properties.put("remote.connections", "hcl01,hcl02");

// Host Controller
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.port", "8443");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.host", "10.0.0.1");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.protocol", "https-remoting");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS", "true");
properties.put("remote.connection.hrl01.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "true");
properties.put("remote.connection.hrl01.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS", "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.port", "8443");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.host", "10.0.0.2");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.protocol", "https-remoting");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS", "true");
properties.put("remote.connection.hrl02.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "true");
properties.put("remote.connection.hrl02.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS", "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");

// Build SLSB Lookup String
String appName = "/"; //name of ear containg ejb
String moduleName = "testapp/"; //name of ejb jar w/o extension
String distinctName = "/"; //any distinct name set within jboss for this deployment
String beanName = Login.class.getSimpleName(); //name of the bean we're looking up
String viewClassName = LoginRemote.class.getName(); //name of the bean interface
System.out.println("beanName=" + beanName + " viewClassName=" + viewClassName);
lookupSLSB = "ejb:" + appName + moduleName + distinctName + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;

// Configure EJB Lookup
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
context = new InitialContext(props);

properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.username", au.getUsername());
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl01.password", au.getPassword());
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.username", au.getUsername());
properties.put("remote.connection.hcl02.password", au.getPassword());

// JBoss Cluster Setup (using properties above)
EJBClientConfiguration cc = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(properties);
ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(cc);
EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);

LoginRemote bean = (LoginRemote)context.lookup(lookupSLSB);
System.out.println("NIC [From bean]: Class=\"" + bean.getStr() + "\"");
```

Comment: Is this setup a rare combination or something? I haven't been getting hits on any of my JavaEE/WildFly questions. I have a hard time finding answers in some cases too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. After dumping traffic it appeared that the queries were being sent to the database. I enabled query logging on the database and found that they were being received, but there was a permission issue with the database user. After granting privileges to the tables being queried, the communication was successful.